# Creating objects in JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create objects in JS for the first time (for a game engine), but I am not able to establish the properties. I have the following code:

```
function door(x, y, goto, key) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.goto = goto;
    this.key = key;
}
```

But, when I call the function

```
var door1 = door(1,2,3,4);
```

It says 'x' does not exist. I have done some experiments changing variables names, and it refers to 'this.x', not the x i pass as a parameter. Does anyone know how can I set the value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the new keyword...

```
var door1 = new door(1,2,3,4);
```